# Shell into faasd function container

Tags: docker, containerd, openfaas

I am working with faasd and I want to troubleshoot my function. I have a connectivity issue from within the function when I try to reach an external server. I can reach the external server from the the host where faasdd is deployed, but not from within the function.

Now I focus on troubleshooting this by logging into the function container and do some network checks from there. The problem I am asking for, is: How can I log into that function's container? I see nothing on `docker ps` or `docker container list` in the machine that hosts faasd.

I did not find any faasd documentation about this. Does someone know how could I log into the faasd function container?

Thanks a lot,
Gabriel

Answer (score 3):

I found the way. Faasd uses containerd, so the way to log into the function container was the following:

```sh
ctr -n openfaas-fn task exec -t --exec-id <whatever> <name_of_the_function> bash
```